# Copy certificate into users ICA Store - GPO

Tags: powershell, group-policy, certificate

I want to copy a certificate into the users intermediate certification authorities store. Is there a way to achieve this via a group policy or a powershell script?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done via GPO:
Computer Configuration –> Policies –> Windows Settings –> Security Settings –> Public Key Policies –> Intermediate Certification Authorities

Comment: But then it puts the Cert in the Computer Cert Store and not in the specific User Cert Store :/